# Why is "HealthCloudUser is not a valid Features value" for Scratch Org?

Tags: salesforcedx, health-cloud

SFDX CLI doesn't allow to create a scratch org with the "HealthCloudUser" feature enabled. Our CI and development workflow requires it as our org uses the HealthCloud package.

We were able to create scratch orgs with the definition file, and several days back this functionality stopped working.

Scratch Org Definition File:

```
{
    "orgName": "Khealth-Scratch-ORG",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "hasSampleData": false,
    "features": [
        "AdditionalFieldHistory:40",
        "Communities",
        "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
        "DebugApex",
        "DefaultWorkflowUser",
        "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
        "HealthCloudUser",
        "Knowledge",
        "Macros",
        "LightningScheduler",
        "LightningServiceConsole",
        "LiveAgent",
        "PersonAccounts",
        "PlatformCache",
        "RecordTypes",
        "SalesforceContentUser",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "ServiceUser",
        "Sites",
        "StateAndCountryPicklist"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableCommunityWorkspaces": true,
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
            "enableCspNotesOnAccConPref": true
        },
        "emailAdministrationSettings": {

        },
        "experienceBundleSettings": {
            "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
        },
        "knowledgeSettings": {
            "defaultLanguage": "en_US",
            "enableKnowledge": true,
            "enableLightningKnowledge": true
        },
        "liveAgentSettings": {
            "enableLiveAgent": true
        },
        "omniChannelSettings": {
            "enableOmniChannel": true,
            "enableOmniSkillsRouting": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableMiddleName": true,
            "enableNameSuffix": true
        },
        "quoteSettings": {
            "enableQuote" : true
        },
        "enhancedNotesSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedNotes": true,
            "enableTasksOnEnhancedNotes": true
        },
        "pathAssistantSettings": {
            "pathAssistantEnabled": true,
            "canOverrideAutoPathCollapseWithUserPref": true
        },
        "sharingSettings": {
            "enableAssetSharing": true,
            "enableExternalSharingModel": true,
            "enablePortalUserCaseSharing": true,
            "enablePortalUserVisibility": true,
            "enableStandardReportVisibility": true
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error message that we started to see:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ci-with-health-cloud -v k:production
ERROR running force:org:create:  HealthCloudUser is not a valid Features value.
```

"[HealthCloudUser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_healthclouduser)" is a valid feature based on the official documentation (and it was working for us for several weeks)

It is a blocker for us because if an org doesn't have this feature enabled, we can't install HealthCloud managed package.

Note, I have opened a Salesforce case, but I am still waiting for their answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen a similar issue reported by other users in Summer'22 scratch orgs. There is already an investigation(#W-11279040) filed for this behavior with the concerned Salesforce Product team.

Using "**HealthCloudAddOn**" in the features section of Scratch Org Definition file, instead of "HealthCloudUser" fixed the issue. You can use this as a workaround.

Hope this helps you!

---

Known issue link: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002rIfZQAU

Comment: You saved my day, @Swetha. Thank you! This workaround solved the issue.

Comment: So glad to know :)